# cuando cambio de indice en dropdown este se recarga y no me da el indice seleccionado

Tags: c#, dropdownlist

Actualmente quiero que mi dropdown me de el indice seleccionado para despues obtener su valor y eso enviarlo a una consulta que tengo en entity framework.

Pero el problema es que selecciono mi dropdownList y recarga y por ende pierde el valor seleccionado y por eso siempre me da 0, aunque no deberia de hacerlo.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SelectMateria" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectMateria_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Nombre" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker form-control" AutoPostBack="True" data-style="btn-white" data-header="Materia" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Código trasero:

```
    protected void SelectMateria_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IndexText.Text = SelectMateria.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
```

Cunado envió mi selectedindex a el input de asp me da como resultado siempre 0, ya lo intente hacer sin el autopostback pero así no ingresa al método y con la propiedad de EnableViewState="True" pero de igual forma siguió sin funcionar.

Comment: Colocaste un breakpoint y revisaste SelectMateria? puede que no se este cargando bien la información

Comment: @VictorPerdomo si ya hice breakpoints y si lo carga bien, porque si lo hago con jquery si me da el valor al cambiar el select, pero me gustaría mas si fuera con c#

Comment: El problema no esta en el autopostback acabo de realizar una prueba y funciona coloca esto IndexText.Text = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex.ToString(); muestra la porción de codigo que utilizas para llenar los elementos de tu dropdownlist

Comment: Como estas llenado los elementos del `DropDownList`?